# function becoming object after passing to another function

Tags: javascript, lambda

My Code is Simple

```
var core ={
  f: function(obj){
    console.log(toString.call(obj));
  }
}
```

Which should display `[object Function]`
if I pass another function to it like `core.f(function(){})`,

and it does the same if I paste the `core.f` in Chrome inspector.
But that anonymous function becomes `[object Object]` if the `core.f` is loaded through a script with `<script src>`

Comment: How did you define `toString`? If it's `Object.prototype.toString`, then it's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're testing in a console, they probably have a local `toString` that resolves to `Object.prototype.toString`.

You should make your own local reference if you don't want the full prototype path.

---

In Chrome, I show a different `toString` than `window.toString`...

```
window.toString === toString; // false
```

---

The `toString` reference does successfully resolve to `Object.prototype.toString`...

```
Object.prototype.toString === toString; // true
```

...so you can see that they've created their own local reference that shadows the global.

Comment: I am using `toString` to check type of object. should I use `window.toString` instead inside `core.f` ?

Comment: No, you should use the same `toString` that the console is using. That's `Object.prototype.toString`. It's a generic `toString()`, and the only one that will return the internal *[[Class]]* property, which can give insight into the type of object.